# Draw Square with OpenGL ES for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I am trying to draw a rectangle using the GLPaint example project provided by apple. I have tried modifying the vertices but cannot get a rectangle to appear on the screen. The finger painting works perfectly. Am I missing something in my renderRect method?

```
- (void)renderRect {

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

    // Replace the implementation of this method to do your own custom drawing.
    static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.33f,
        0.5f, -0.33f,
        -0.5f,  0.33f,
        0.5f,  0.33f,
    };

    static float transY = 0.0f;

    glTranslatef(0.0f, (GLfloat)(sinf(transY)/2.0f), 0.0f);


    // Render the vertex array
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


    // Display the buffer
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}
```

The rest of the project is set up stock to allow drawing on the screen but just for reference these are the gl settings that are set.

```
// Set the view's scale factor
self.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;

// Setup OpenGL states
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
CGRect frame = self.bounds;
CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
// Setup the view port in Pixels
glOrthof(0, frame.size.width * scale, 0, frame.size.height * scale, -1, 1);
glViewport(0, 0, frame.size.width * scale, frame.size.height * scale);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
// Set a blending function appropriate for premultiplied alpha pixel data
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
glTexEnvf(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES, GL_TRUE);
glPointSize(width / brushScale);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        30.0f,  300.0f,//-0.5f, -0.33f,
        280.0f, 300.0f,//0.5f, -0.33f,
        30.0f,  170.0f,//-0.5f,  0.33f,
        280.0f, 170.0f,//0.5f,  0.33f,
    };
```

That's definitely too much. OpenGL has normalized screen coords in range [-1..1]. So you have to convert device coords to normalized ones.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using -1 to 1 range. I missed on the post when pasting code. Now even with normalized screen coords, I still am seeing nothing. The commented coords are from the square used in the iOS OpenGLES template code.  I've tried changing colors as well to no avail.

Comment: try to add glLoadIdentity();   after    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

Comment: Nope no luck. Now the code does set up a brush texture for drawing. Maybe this is causing the square not to draw properly because of the texture. Here is the source : [link](http://pastebin.com/UhjHyJiG) You will notice that renderLineFromPoint uses glPointSize and glBlendFunc before rendering the vertex array. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your setup code is changing the projection matrix, so your screen coords should be origin=0,0 size= frame.size.width, frame.size.height. Also, the translation is cumulative since there is no call to  glLoadIdentity() in your drawing code. Also, for good measure set the drawing color to something obvious (I usually use red (1,0,0,1)).

Answer (score 0):

Issues are:

(1) the following code:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    CGRect frame = self.bounds;
    CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
    // Setup the view port in Pixels
    glOrthof(0, frame.size.width * scale, 0, frame.size.height * scale, -1, 1);
    glViewport(0, 0, frame.size.width * scale, frame.size.height * scale);
```

Establishes that the on-screen coordinates range from (0, 0) in the lower left to frame.size in the upper right. In other words, one OpenGL unit is one iPhone point. So your array of:

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.33f,
    0.5f, -0.33f,
    -0.5f,  0.33f,
    0.5f,  0.33f,
};
```

Is less than 1 pixel in size.

(2) you have the following in the setup:

```
    brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Particle.png"].CGImage;

    /* ...brushImage eventually becomes the current texture... */

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

You subsequently fail to supply texture coordinates for your quad. Probably you want to disable `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

So the following:

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0,  10.0f,
    90.0,  0.0f,
    90.0f, 10.0f,
};



glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

// Render the vertex array
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Will produce a white quad 90 points wide and 10 points tlal in the lower left of the screen.