# Draw triangle using OpenGL ES for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I am not an OpenGL expert and am having difficulty drawing a triangle to the screen. I am modifying an old sample project from Apple (GLPaint) that I have ported to Swift. The project is a basic finger drawing application, and I would like to modify it so that I can draw shapes.

I am able to draw points (GL_POINTS), but not triangles (GL_TRIANGLES)

I found a similar post where a user was attempting to do the same as me, but it did not help:

[Draw Square with OpenGL ES for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009014/draw-square-with-opengl-es-for-ios)

Below is the code that I use to successfully draw points to the screen:

```swift
        EAGLContext.setCurrent(context)
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER.ui, viewFramebuffer)

        let squareVertices : [GLfloat] = [
            500.0, 500.0,
            1000.0,  500.0,
            1000.0,  1000.0,
        ]

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D.ui);
        glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX.ui)
        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX.ui, 2, GL_FLOAT.ui, GL_FALSE.ub, 0, squareVertices)

        glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id)
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS.ui, 0, 3)

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER.ui, viewRenderbuffer)
        context.presentRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER.l)
```

Below is initialization code:

```swift
    private func initGL() -> Bool {
        // Generate IDs for a framebuffer object and a color renderbuffer
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer)
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer)

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER.ui, viewFramebuffer)
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER.ui, viewRenderbuffer)
        // This call associates the storage for the current render buffer with the EAGLDrawable (our CAEAGLLayer)
        // allowing us to draw into a buffer that will later be rendered to screen wherever the layer is (which corresponds with our view).
        context.renderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER.l, from: (self.layer as! EAGLDrawable))
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER.ui, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0.ui, GL_RENDERBUFFER.ui, viewRenderbuffer)

        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER.ui, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH.ui, &backingWidth)
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER.ui, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT.ui, &backingHeight)

        // For this sample, we do not need a depth buffer. If you do, this is how you can create one and attach it to the framebuffer:
        //    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        //    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
        //    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, backingWidth, backingHeight);
        //    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

        if glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER.ui) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE.ui {
            NSLog("failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER.ui))
            return false
        }

        // Setup the view port in Pixels
        glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight)

        // Create a Vertex Buffer Object to hold our data
        glGenBuffers(1, &vboId)

        // Load the brush texture
        brushTexture = self.texture(fromName: "ParticleNew.png")

        // Load shaders
        self.setupShaders()

        // Enable blending and set a blending function appropriate for premultiplied alpha pixel data
        glEnable(GL_BLEND.ui)
        glBlendFunc(GL_ONE.ui, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.ui)

        return true
    }
```

To draw a triangle, I tried changing glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS.ui, 0, 3) to glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES.ui, 0, 3) but nothing was drawn to the screen. There were also no error messages printed to console.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.